# wcf service with params

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

the contract def is

```
    [OperationContract]
    DataSet myfunc(string a, params object[] args);
```

but the proxy is generated like so by the add service ref wizard

```
    public System.Data.DataSet myfunc(string a, object[] args) {
        return base.Channel.GetDataSet(a, args);
    }
```

what gives ? both are .net 4.0 projects

I can change the proxy but the changes will be lost on update

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your question is, but I'm guessing you're seeing problems because of your use of `params` there.

WSDL doesn't deal with optional parameters like that.

Is that what you're getting at?

If that's the case, then your best bet may be to do what the proxy generated code is doing instead.  Pass an array of objects (though you may run into trouble trying to pass just any old object since some won't be serializable or interoperable).

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with the optional parameters though, so I can't tell you exactly what to do instead.

Comment: Edited answer.  Not sure that's useful unless I know what you're really trying to do.

Comment: If you are using svcutil.exe you can add params keyword again inside methods parameters inside the client class generated where they are missing `public System.Data.DataSet myfunc(string a, params object[] args)`